# Android Amplify Storage - Set access id and secret key

Tags: android, amazon-s3, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I would like to integrate Amplify into my android app and in particular the storage to upload files to an existing bucket. I set the *amplifyconfiguration* configuration json with *bucket*, *region* and *endpoint*.
I need to use the access id and secret key as authentication but I can't find a way to set them.
At the moment i cannot integrate other forms of authentication.
I would like to insert them programmatically.

I did some tests directly with the AWS Android SDK which, being at a lower level, allows me to enter these parameters.

I'm using *com.amplifyframework:aws-storage-s3:2.14.10*

Thanks for your help!